# Not able to launch iOS application using Appium Desktop to inspect the element

Tags: appium, appium-ios

Test Environment: iOS 11, OSX 10.12, Appium Desktop 1.2.5, Xcode 8.1

**Desired Capabilities :**

```
{
  "platformName": "iOS",
  "deviceName": "iPhone 7",
  "udid": "93551a7d721b790b0188642402f1ada96892b816",
  "app": "/Users/globalit/Desktop/IntegrationApp.app",
  "automationName": "XCUITest"
}
```

I am able to launch integration app in the device using xcode.
also successfully deployed web-driver agent in my device.

But i am getting following error when i tried to launch my ios application via appium desktop.

**Error:**

An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Unable to start WebDriverAgent session because of xcodebuild failure: "Could not proxy command to remote server. Original error: Error: socket hang up". Make sure you follow the tutorial at https://github.com/appium/appium-xcuitest-driver/blob/master/docs/real-device-config.md. Try to remove the WebDriverAgentRunner application from the device if it is installed and reboot the device.

**Appium Logs:**

```
XCUITest] Failed to create WDA session. Retrying...
[BaseDriver] Event 'wdaSessionAttempted' logged at 1509096179356 (14:52:59 GMT+0530 (IST))
[XCUITest] Sending createSession command to WDA
[JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [GET /status] to [GET http://localhost:8100/status] with no body
[XCUITest] Failed to create WDA session. Retrying...
[XCUITest] Unable to start WebDriverAgent session because of xcodebuild failure: "Could not proxy command to remote server. Original error: Error: socket hang up". Make sure you follow the tutorial at https://github.com/appium/appium-xcuitest-driver/blob/master/docs/real-device-config.md. Try to remove the WebDriverAgentRunner application from the device if it is installed and reboot the device.
[XCUITest] Quitting and uninstalling WebDriverAgent, then retrying
[XCUITest] Shutting down sub-processes
[XCUITest] Shutting down iproxy process (pid 576)
[XCUITest] iproxy exited with code 'null'
[XCUITest] Shutting down xcodebuild process (pid 577)
[XCUITest] xcodebuild exited with code 'null' and signal 'SIGTERM'
[XCUITest] Removing WDA application from device
[XCUITest] Error: Unable to start WebDriverAgent session because of xcodebuild failure: "Could not proxy command to remote server. Original error: Error: socket hang up". Make sure you follow the tutorial at https://github.com/appium/appium-xcuitest-driver/blob/master/docs/real-device-config.md. Try to remove the WebDriverAgentRunner application from the device if it is installed and reboot the device.
    at XCUITestDriver.quitAndUninstall$ (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/lib/driver.js:381:13)
    at tryCatch (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:67:40)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke [as _invoke] (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:315:22)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:100:21)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:136:37)
 Error: Unable to start WebDriverAgent session because of xcodebuild failure: "Could not proxy command to remote server. Original error: Error: socket hang up". Make sure you follow the tutorial at https://github.com/appium/appium-xcuitest-driver/blob/master/docs/real-device-config.md. Try to remove the WebDriverAgentRunner application from the device if it is installed and reboot the device.
    at XCUITestDriver.quitAndUninstall$ (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/lib/driver.js:381:13)
    at tryCatch (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:67:40)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke [as _invoke] (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:315:22)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:100:21)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:136:37)
[XCUITest] Not clearing log files. Use `clearSystemFiles` capability to turn on.
[iOSLog] Stopping iOS log capture
[MJSONWP] Encountered internal error running command: Error: Unable to start WebDriverAgent session because of xcodebuild failure: "Could not proxy command to remote server. Original error: Error: socket hang up". Make sure you follow the tutorial at https://github.com/appium/appium-xcuitest-driver/blob/master/docs/real-device-config.md. Try to remove the WebDriverAgentRunner application from the device if it is installed and reboot the device.
    at XCUITestDriver.quitAndUninstall$ (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/lib/driver.js:381:13)
    at tryCatch (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:67:40)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke [as _invoke] (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:315:22)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:100:21)
    at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke (/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/appium/node_modules/babel-runtime/regenerator/runtime.js:136:37)
[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session 500 118446 ms - 526
```

Comment: I'm assuming you've followed the steps in the tutorial? No luck?

Is your simulator closed when you attempt your run? I've not seen issue w/ Appium Desktop not be able to blow away another simulator session, but I have seen problems with my IDE attempting to do so.

Comment: Are you able to upgrade to Xcode 9?

Comment: i am using xcode 8.1. i did not tried to upgrade. Do i have to upgrade?

Comment: Yes i tried this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2_xHmofGgUE.

Comment: I am using real device iPhone 6 with iOS 11.

Comment: Can you try using a simulated device? That can resolve certain provisioning issues, which it sounds like what your issue may be.

Comment: I tried with a simulator and getting following error. An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Unable to launch WebDriverAgent because of xcodebuild failure: "xcodebuild failed with code 65". i am able to build both wedriver agent and application successfully into the ios simulator. But not able to open via appium desktop

Comment: Perhaps http://discuss.appium.io/t/xcodebuild-failed-with-code-65-warning-the-server-did-not-provide-any-stacktrace-information-command-duration-or-timeout-32-63-seconds/12756/2 will resolve?